# how can I count the number of ways to tile n*n board using the 2 x 1 tiles

Tags: algorithm

I solved problem counting the number of ways to tile 2 x n, 3 x n board using the 2 x 1 tiles.
But I couldn't think of any ideas of counting the number of ways to tile n x n board using the 2 x 1 tiles.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: A half of solution - result is 0 for odd n.

Comment: https://orion.math.iastate.edu/butler/papers/14_02_walks.pdf https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domino_tiling#Counting_tilings_of_regions